# Supress "Disabled by administrator" messages

Tags: windows-10

Not sure if this is possible, but I have disabled access to task manager on machines and would like to suppress the message saying "Task Manager has been disabled by your administrator"

If ctrl + shift + esc is pressed, task manager silently fails to exectute. However, if started from the Start Menu, or command prompt, the 'error' message pops up. It seems like  the message is presented from taskmanager itself, as process explorer shows taskmanager running and killing the process causes the message to close, but since you get this message for other disabled apps I was wondering if there might be a registry entry that could be created/edited to suppress this.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't suppress those (policy) messages in a supported way.